# Vertical spacing around lhs2TeX code block in floats

Tags: spacing, floats, lhs2tex

How do I get the appropriate vertical space around a `\begin{code}`/`\end{code}` or `\begin{spec}`/`\end{spec}` in a figure?

Here is a basic example with `fancyhdr` added to show the top of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[C]{}
%include polycode.fmt
\begin{document}
Some text.
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{code}
main = putStrLn "Hello, world!"
\end{code}
\caption{Hello world example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Basic example]

Unfortunately, when you compare this figure to another without code, the spacing
above and below the code is noticeably more.

When looking at the code of lhs2TeX, I noticed the use of `\abovedisplayskip`
and `\belowdisplayskip`. So I tried setting those to `0pt`:

```
...
\begin{figure}[t]
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{code}
...
```

[image: Using <code>\abovedisplayskip</code> and <code>\belowdisplayskip</code>]

This looks more like other figures with just text. However, if I want to center
the code, I get extra vertical space again:

```
...
\begin{figure}[t]
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{center}
...
```

[image: With centering]

What's the recommended way to get the appropriate vertical spacing around a (possibly centered) code block in a figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saying `\texths` in the `figure`. That should remove all outer space and should treat the code block more or less as if it was plain text.

Comment: Excellent. That avoids the need for `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`. The centering seems to have the same space-increasing effect on plain text and code blocks, which suggests that it is independent of lhs2TeX. Any idea about how to fix that?

Comment: Here's the [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2652/16670): use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}`/`\end{center}` inside a float.