# Indentation of a code block in lhs2TeX

Tags: indentation, lhs2tex

What's the (quick and) easy way to set the indentation of a `\begin{code}`/`\end{code}` or `\begin{spec}`/`\end{spec}`? That is, I want to set only the indentation of the whole block, not the indentation of the columns in the code (which can be configured by `\hsindent` as described in the [documentation](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/)).

One solution would be to use `\texths` (as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186335/16670)) and a `minipage`, but I suspect there are better/nicer options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, lhs2TeX uses `\mathindent` to determine the amount of indentation. So you can say

```
\setlength\mathindent{4cm}
```

to get an absurd amount of indentation.

You can get more flexibility by using `\hscodestyle`. This command is executed for every code block, and you can put arbitrary style-changing commands in there. For example:

```
\renewcommand\hscodestyle{%
   \setlength\leftskip{-1cm}%
   \small
}
```

would change both indentation (to a value independent of `\mathindent`) and set the size of the code block.