# Vertical spacing around align in a figure

Tags: spacing, floats, align

Math environments like align put vertical space around them, to separate them from the text. This is all well, and if I wanted to change that, I could check [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align).

However, these environments also add vertical space (one `\abovedisplayskip`) above the math environment inside a floating figure. This way, the first line of the page is not aligned with the other first lines, which looks strange and wastes spaces.

As a MWE, I have this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe,amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is regular text on the first line
\begin{align*}
\text{There is space before this, which is good}
\end{align*}
More regular textx.
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{align*}
\text{This is not on the first line}
\end{align*}
\caption{A figure with extra space}
\end{figure}
Some text for the second page.
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Extra space on the right!]

Am I expecting too much from Tex if I expect that space not to be there? And is there a way to fix this centrally, without affecting other vertical spaces around math environments?

Comment: Could you show us a compilable example please?

Comment: Done. You probably want to click on the image to have a closer look.

Comment: If you don't want gaps or equation numbers, just use \hfil $x=a$\par or \makebox[\textwidth]{$x=a$} although you might want to add a \mathstrut.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why you want to do such things and how this would look like? I can't think about many cases where an `align` would be wrapped in a `figure`. For the few cases, just do `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` as first line of your `figure`.

Comment: @Larifari, I want the first line of the pages to align. And there are environments derived from `align` etc. ([e.g. lhs2tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186334/vertical-spacing-around-lhs2tex-code-block-in-floats)), I’m using `align` only as an example here.

Comment: What about two aligns in one figure. Could this happen?

Comment: Yes, sure. Hence I wrote “without affecting other vertical spaces around math environments”. The obvious “redefine `figure` to set `\abovedisplayskip=0pt`” would not work well.
I’m surprised none else seems to be bothered by this extra space.

Comment: BTW, here is a real-world-example of the problem, see [page 3 of this paper](http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-Haskell15.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do this for the case of several `align`s in one `figure`. I have never seen anyone using display math in a `figure` and I do not get the value of doing so. So I just give the solution for getting rid of `\abovedisplayskip` in `figure`s also this is not what you are looking for.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\def\@floatboxreset{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    
    This is regular text on the first line
    \begin{align*}
        \text{There is space before this, which is good}
    \end{align*}
    More regular text.
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{align*}
            \text{This is on the first line}
        \end{align*}
        \caption{A figure without any extra space}
    \end{figure}
    Some text for the second page.
\end{document}
```

Your case is really hard to code as you have to check, whether it is the first or any other `align` inside your float. Maybe you should better write your own environment `myfirstalign*` or alike.